# iOS (swift) old launch screen displaying after upgrade the application on iphone 11 , 11 pro , 11 pro max with iOS 13.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, splash-screen, launch-screen

**Steps for replicate :**

1. Create demo project in Xcode 11.3.
2. Add some text on launch screen.
3. Run Project on iphone (real device) 11, 11 pro , 11 pro max with iOS version 13.3.
4. When project is compiled and application launched stop the debugging process.
5. Now change text on Launch screen and debbugg project again.

**Result :** Launch screen text not changed. Old text showing on Launch screen .

Comment: yes, it is known issue, sometimes after updating Launchscreen, it still shows the older one, what you can do for real device is, delete app and install again and for simulator, reset simulator, after these steps it will show your latest content.

Answer (score 1):

The system caches launch images and doesn't clear them very proactively. You can add code to clear the cache yourself, although I'd stick this behind a feature flag as circumventing the cache isn't something you probably want to do all the time.

```
import UIKit

public extension UIApplication {

    func clearLaunchScreenCache() {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: NSHomeDirectory()+"/Library/SplashBoard")
        } catch {
            print("Failed to delete launch screen cache: \(error)")
        }
    }

}
```

Code snippet taken from: https://rambo.codes/posts/2019-12-09-clearing-your-apps-launch-screen-cache-on-ios

Comment: Hi Wilk0, Thanks for your response. I actually already have tried this solution. I did add this code inside "main.swift", the entry point of the application. It is not working for the very first launch of the application, immediate after upgrade of the application. However, for 2nd and launches after that (after upgrade), i am getting the new launchScreen. I also have tried to solve it by renaming of launch-image, launch-screen storyboard and related assets. But, on the very first launch after upgrade, application is still showing old launch-screen.

Answer (score 0):

Launch screen image update issue :-

1. Go to about this Mac
2. Go to storage
3. Open manage
4. Click the developer options
5. Clear the Xcode cache
6. Open simulator
7. See with left corner “Device”
8. Click “Erase all content and settings”
9. Go to Xcode
10. Open the launch storyboard xib
11. Remove the old image view and add the new UI Imageview.
12. Set constraints
13. Now run problem solved.